# Magento 2: how to get product details using Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, knockoutjs, quote

In Magento 2 how we can get the product details using Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote

Answer (score 1):

Use checkoutConfig.quoteData where you will get all the data for the product which is added to cart.

Comment: could you please send me the full data how I can use. Is it like var quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;

Comment: Yes you can access the data from that variable